# SQL Inner Join to compare the result

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and want to compare two tables using inner join and then use the result to compare it with the third table and so on. Also the third table does not share the same column name as compared in the first two.

Below is the SQL statement to compare two tables.

```
SELECT WORKLOAD_ITEM_ID wid 
FROM OUTPUT o 
INNER JOIN workload_item wi ON O.WORKLOAD_ITEM_ID = wi.WORKLOAD_ITEM_ID
```

Now whatever is returned I want to use that and do an inner join with a third table which does not have a column `WORKLOAD_ITEM_ID`. So the question is how to save and compare the result?

Please Help!

Comment: The 3rd table doesn't have to share the same column _name_, it would just need some column which has a value in common (or even a value deduced from an expression) with one of the other two tables. Joins aren't about column names so much as they are about creating "true" expressions between tables.

Comment: So what _is_ the relationship of the third table to the first two? How would you use the first two to limit the third? Therein lies the joining relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this to hold records in temp table

```
INSERT INTO #WORKLOAD_ITEM_TEMP
SELECT WORKLOAD_ITEM_ID wid 
FROM OUTPUT o 
INNER JOIN workload_item wi ON O.WORKLOAD_ITEM_ID = wi.WORKLOAD_ITEM_ID
```

Then with your third table made a join with this `#WORKLOAD_ITEM_TEMP` table.
Now you have to decide on which column need to put inner join. Either add a common column between output result set and third table or use just cross join.

I think you need to reevaluate your Database structure and make efficient tables relationship.